# Is there a way to render LaTeX equation which is provided through Delta in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, latex, wysiwyg, quill, delta

I am working on a app in which I have to display rich text. So this rich text will be coming from Quill Rich Text Editor. Quill exports this rich text in Delta format which is basically a json which contains text along with it's attribute.
ex -

```
{"ops":[
   {"insert":"This is a big header"},
   {"attributes":{"header":1},"insert":"\n"},
   {"insert":"And this is a smaller header"},
   {"attributes":{"header":2}, "insert":"\n"},
   {"insert":"And this is plaintext\n"}
]}
```

Now, here's the main problem. The delta I will be working with will be containing LaTeX equations (a format in which complex mathematical equations are stored).

I want to show this rich text along with equations in Flutter.

I have found a package **flutter_quill** which renders **delta** into rich text but does not renders latex equation.

This is the small part of Delta I want to show in flutter

```
{"ops":[
   {"insert": "This is the Latex Equation"},
   {
      "attributes": {"header": 1},
      "insert": "\n"
   },
   {"insert": "\\[x = \\frac{-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}\\]\n"}
]}
```

This is how it is rendering the delta.
[This is how it is rendering the Delta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqm4k.png)

Expected result
[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gAcO.png)

There's package called Flutter_tex which helps to render LaTeX equation.

**The main problem I am facing is how to detect LaTeX equations in Delta and render them using flutter_tex.**

ps- I used ChatGPT for solution, but the solution provided is outdated ig. It was something related to using custom renderer along with Flutter Quill to render equations.

Answer (score 0):

You could match the value of each `insert` (or where you expect a latex math expression to occur) against a regular expression that checks for the beginning and ending of a latex math equation. [This article](https://www.docx2latex.com/tutorials/mathematical-equations-latex/#:%7E:text=Mathematical%20modes,-For%20writing%20math&text=The%20inline%20mode%20uses%20one,%7D%20%5Cend%7Bequation%7D.) shows what possibilities there are for beginning and ending mathematical expressions.

Note: The above solution should work in most cases. But users could add text that contain these sequences but don't want them to be rendered as an equation.

Idea: I am not familiar with Quill, but maybe there is a way to add an `attribute` or some kind of flag to each `insert` to indicate to the parser how this `insert` should be treated. For example: `plain-text`, `latex-equation`, ...